# Why does .NET Framework prerequisite not run from same location of my setup file?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, setup-project

I have created a setup project in c# and i had choose dot net framework 3.5 as it's prerequisites and i set the option "*Download from the same location as my application*". But while it assumed to be run from local when i run the **Setup.msi** it goes through the internet to install the .NET Framework 3.5.

Could anybody please tell me WHY?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Application Deployment Prerequisites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/h4k032e1.aspx) (emphasis added):

> ... Visual Studio generates a Windows executable program named Setup.exe, also known as a bootstrapper. **The bootstrapper is responsible for installing these prerequisites** before your application runs.

The **msi** file is just a windows installer database, and isn't capable of performing bootstrapping actions.